# Можно ли сделать отдельный файл Less где будут храниться все переменные

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

Всем привет!
Ребят, такая проблема,- в данный момент делать стили пытаюсь на `LESS`.
Я разбил один на файл на модули, каждый файл для каждой категории.

*Вопрос*: можно ли сделать еще один файл `less`, для того, чтобы хранить в нем переменные?
Если можно, то объясните пожалуйста, как это сделать и правильно подключить!
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, нужно просто создать отдельный файл с расширением `.less`, и потом в основной файл подключить с помощью `@import`.

> **Импорт**
>
> Работа импорта осуществляется, в значительной мере, как и ожидалось.
>   Вы можете импортировать `.less` файл, и все переменные объявленные в нем,
>   будут доступны к использованию. Расширение `.less` необязательно
>   указывать для файлов.

```
@import "library"; // library.less
@import "typo.css";
```

[Источник](https://less-lang.info/guide/#features-overview-feature-importing)

Лично я использую `SASS`. Я бы и вас посоветовал, ибо и документация на русском, и много у него возможностей, но это мое личное предпочтение). Там модули подключаються по средству `_module.scss //(.sass)`.

[image: scr]

Comment: спасибо большое! Я только начинаю работать с препроцессорами, думаю, что чуть позже я последую вашему совету